# Print out message only once from the for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to find if a specific string is contained inside the elements of a list. If the string is found, I want to print out "String found", otherwise "String not found".
But, the code I came up with, makes multiple prints of "String not found". I know the reason why, but I don't know how to fix it and print it only one of the messages once.

```
animals=["dog.mouse.cow","horse.tiger.monkey",
         "badger.lion.chimp","trok.cat.    bee"]
      for i in animals :
          if "cat" in i:
              print("String found")
          else:
              print("String not found")
```

~

Comment: You might want to change your if to: `if "cat" in i.split("."):` (assuming all strings in animals are separated by ".") otherwise for e.g. `"caterpillar.dog"` would return True. I'm not sure if this the behaviour you want.

Comment: @Jdog Nicely spotted. However, that's not a problem in my case.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Add a `break` statement in the `if` block when the string is found, and move the `else` to be the `else` of the for loop. If this case if the string is found the loop will break and the else will never be reached, and if the loop doesn't brake the else will be reached and `'String not found'` will be printed.

```
for i in animals:
    if 'cat' in i:
        print('String found')
        break
else:
    print('String not found')
```

Comment: This does not work. If "cat" occurs at the last element of the list, you still get the "String not found" printed multiple times.

Comment: @ArditSulce sorry my mistake fixed it.

Answer (score 4):

There is a shorter way to do this in one line. :)

```
>>> animals=["dog.mouse.cow","horse.tiger.monkey","badger.lion.chimp","trok.cat.    bee"]
>>> print "Found" if any(["cat" in x for x in animals]) else "Not found"
Found
>>> animals = ["foo", "bar"]
>>> print "Found" if any(["cat" in x for x in animals]) else "Not found"
Not found
```

This relies on the fact that sum will return 0 if every item in the list is False, and will return positive number (True) otherwise.

Comment: `any` is probably preferable over `sum`, although the result is the same.

Comment: Smacks head ... of course!! Edited the solution to include your improvement

Answer (score 2):

`any` returns `True` if `bool(x)` is `True` for any `x` in the iterable passed to it. In this case the generator expression `"cat" in a for a in animals`. Which checks if `"cat"` is contained within any of the elements inside the list `animals`. This method has the advantage of not needing to traverse the whole list in *all* cases.

```
if any("cat" in a for a in animals):
    print "String found"
else:
    print "String not found"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [next()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next):

```
next(("String found" for animal in animals if "cat" in animal), "String not found")
```

DEMO:

```
>>> animals=["dog.mouse.cow","horse.tiger.monkey","badger.lion.chimp","trok.cat.    bee"]
>>> next(("String found" for animal in animals if "cat" in animal), "String not found")
'String found'
>>> animals=["dog.mouse.cow","horse.tiger.monkey"]
>>> next(("String found" for animal in animals if "cat" in animal), "String not found")
'String not found'
```